# Handle Securtiy Warning pop-up in FireFox with Selenium IDE

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-ide

I am using Selenium IDE 2.5.0.

When used Firefox 23.0.1, it displays "Security Warning" popup window with "Continue" 
and "Cancel" option. Once this popup window displays it does not allow to 
select anything or view source file before clicking either "Continue" 
and "Cancel"

I tried all the mentioned solutions like,
about:config but there is no security.warn in the list mentioned.

I also tried to disable all warnings in security tab/settings button(warning messages)
[image]

Some one suggested the emulate the 'Enter' key but I could not get the option on how to view pop-up window name as I can't 
view the source files.

Can you help on how to work around on this?

I am struggeling for more than two weeks with this.

Thank you for your suggestions

Amit

Answer (score 0):

At first I would try to get rid of the message. There seams to be a misconfiguration and the browser tries to warn the user.

2) I didn't have the exact message same till now, but closing of alerts work like this:

```
executeScript("window.alert.myAlertText = null;");
executeScript("window.confirm = function(msg){ window.alert.myAlertText = msg; return true; };");
```

Where executeScript just uses the driver as JavascriptExecuter.
This source has to be called before a confirm dialog can happen. It closes any confirm dialog immediately and stores the text for later use.

Comment: I found no way to get rid of the message :( I can't get your snippet wokring, I think it's because the dialog is created by firefox not by the website. The message appears because we try to submit a form from https to http

Comment: 1) Why are you leaving https when the you submit userdata? You don't want to protect it?

Comment: 2) The snipplet should work with the alert-window of firefox. Otherwise a click on the button of the website would be enough. Why isn't the snipplet running. Any exception?

Comment: 1) The non secure page is my local test environment 2) the snippet runs, but nothing happens. I also tried this without selenium: I run this in the js console "window.confirm = function(msg) { return true; }" but the message still appear.

Comment: When the script runs, nothing happens. It causes the change when the alert appears. So run the snipplets, then execute the access which causes the alert, and then the alert, shouldn't appear. The page should just submit.

Comment: @Jordi laforge you are wondering why you would leave https to http. Consider this example: I have an ecommerce site I am doing selenium scripts for, but the testing instances of the website do not run under https. But the testing server for the third party real time payment processor still uses https and so once the order has been completed, it returns from https to http, invoking the browser alert. This kind of problem arises during testing, just testing, and we are just trying to work around it.

Answer (score 0):

```
chooseOkOnNextConfirmation
```

Didn't work for you?

> chooseOkOnNextConfirmation()
>
> Undo the effect of calling chooseCancelOnNextConfirmation. Note that Selenium's overridden window.confirm() function will normally
> automatically return true, as if the user had manually clicked OK, so
> you shouldn't need to use this command unless for some reason you need
> to change your mind prior to the next confirmation. After any
> confirmation, Selenium will resume using the default behavior for
> future confirmations, automatically returning true (OK) unless/until
> you explicitly call chooseCancelOnNextConfirmation for each
> confirmation.
>
> Take note - every time a confirmation comes up, you must consume it with a corresponding getConfirmation, or else the next selenium
> operation will fail.

chooseCancelOnNextConfirmation is also an option